# modifying a Sharepoint Online Excel file in C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, excel

This is the follow up [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837675/programmatically-modifying-a-sharepoint-online-excel-file)

I can't figure out how to write a data table (called datatble1) in C# to a Sharepoint Online Excel file called `ExcelFile.xlsx`.

```
  datatable1= dt1;
   using (var context = new SP.ClientContext(new Uri("https://DomainName.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePoitnSite")))
    {
        var web = context.Web;
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in "Password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("account@domain.com", passWord);
        context.Load(web);
        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(new Uri("https://DomainName.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePoitnSite/Shared%20Documents/ExcelFile.xlsx").AbsolutePath);

        context.Load(file);
        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            //file.SaveBinary(new SP.FileSaveBinaryInformation() { Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("t2.xlsx") });
              
            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph API offers some endpoints that could write tables to Excel files in SharePoint online.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

[image]

You can use rest API or C# SDK:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

BR